# (Typescript) Automatically access child object properties

Tags: typescript

I am new to TS and have a question:

Say I have the following:

```
interface FolderInterface {
   name: string;
   source: {
     type: 'usb'
   },
   // many more properties
}

class FolderImpl {
   folder: FolderInterface
}
```

I have an instance of *FolderImpl*, called *folderImpl*.

What I would like to do is that if *folderImpl.name* is called, it automatically calls *folderImpl.folder.name*.

I am guessing one way would be to copy over the properties, but is there a better way than that?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: What is `Folder`? And what does "map everything to the appropriate field on the folder" mean? Map how? And to what? Please [edit] your question to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want better help here.

Comment: Thank you for your note. This is a theoretical question at this point, and I have edited the question to make it clearer. Since I do not know how to achieve what I have above, I am not sure how to create an example. Please let me know if the above makes sense, otherwise I will think more on how to present the question in a better fashion.

Comment: bro I can't catch you ! every time I try to update my answer you update your question

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. The main idea was that I wanted to use folderImpl.name instead of folderImpl.folder.name to avoid having to make numerous changes. Anyway, It seems like maybe this is not possible.

Comment: are you wanting [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript#inheritance)?

Comment: Hi @about14sheep - I think that might work. Silly of me did not think about that. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Typescript an implements clause can be used to verify that a class conforms to a specific interface

this is not what you are doing, if your class `FolderImpl` has a proprety of type `FolderInterface` it does not have to implement any other class.

```js
class FolderImpl {
   constructor(
    public folder: FolderInterface, public otherProp: string
   ) {
    this.folder = folder;
    this.otherProp = otherProp;
  }
}
```

> is there a way to automatically map everything to the appropriate field on the folder

you don't have to map nothing if you want to declare a const of type `FolderImpl` you do it this way :

```js
const test : FolderImpl =  new FolderImpl({name: 'zab', source: { type : 'usb'}},'ahmed');
```

and you acces your properties like this :

```js
const myFolder = test.folder
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are wanting can also be achieved simply with [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript#inheritance), which is native to javascript. You can create a "parent" class with properties that can be shared between all its "children".

Your parent class:

```js
class Folder {
  name: string;
  source: {
    type: 'usb'
  };
  
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Now you extend this class to your implementation "child" class:

```js
class FolderImp extends Folder {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
  
  // add methods that would be specific to the FolderImp class
  // you can access all the properties of the parent class
  printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

Notice the `super` call, this allows you set the properties of the parent class without declaring them in the child class. So now this will work:

```js
const folderImp = new FolderImp("bin");
folderImp.printName() // prints bin
```